# Polymer 2.0 strange behaviour when removing an item from an observed array

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, frontend, polymer-2.x

While working on an application with Polymer 2.0, I've encountered a problem that is illustrated by this simplified code: https://jsfiddle.net/w912gf8g/33/

```
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+polymer+v2.0.0-rc.2/webcomponentsjs+webcomponents+:master/components/">

<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html">

<root-element></root-element>

<dom-module id="root-element">
  <template>
    <dom-repeat items="[[items]]">
      <template>
        <inner-element inner=[[item]]></inner-element>
      </template>      
    </dom-repeat>   
    <button on-click="_removeItem">Remove the first item</button>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="inner-element">
  <template>
    <h3>Element: {{inner.prop}}</h3>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', () => {
    // Extend Polymer.Element base class
  class RootElement extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() {
    return 'root-element';
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => [{ prop: 1 }, { prop: 2 }, { prop: 3 }],
        notify: true
      }
    }
  }

  _removeItem(){
    this.splice('items', 0, 1);
  }
}

// Register custom element definition using standard platform API
customElements.define(RootElement.is, RootElement);

class InnerElement extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() {
    return 'inner-element';
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  static get properties() {
    return {
      inner: {
        type: Object,
        value: () => {},                            
        notify: true
      }
    }
  }

  static get observers() {
    return [
      '_changed(inner.prop)'
    ]
  }

  _changed(newVal){
    if(this.lastValue != null && this.lastValue !== newVal){
      alert("How on earth does this happen?");
    }

    this.lastValue = newVal;
  }
}

customElements.define(InnerElement.is, InnerElement);  
});
</script>
```

I would expect that after the button is clicked, which invokes removal of the first element, the code that invokes the alert message should never be run, because this indicates that the properties of the array entries have been changed and this makes little sense as the operation was intended to simply remove an entry from the array.

**Question**

Why does this happen? How can this be avoided? Am I using observers or splice method not the way it was designed to be used?

**Side note**

I can guess the reason why this happens is because Polymer is optimized to actually always remove the last DOM element and shifting the data "upwards" before that.

But I cannot understand how can this not cause major side effects in other applications.

Comment: Defining Items property will not return a value like you declared above. You need to return a value something like : `()=>{return [...]}`. Better check property with observer. Or use as i corrected before.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.
I edited it again and, as you can see by trying jsfiddle link out, it works.

Comment: Honestly I think this is a bug.  I've seen several people report this same problem in the last 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add mutable-data as property on your dom-repeat:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]" mutable-data>
```

Please check this page [Data system concepts](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-system)